# Pandas optional extract

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a data set which has the following format:

```
'XX4H30M'
```

I need to extract the numbers in these sequences into two columns ('H', and 'M).

If the format is exactly as described, the following does what I need:

```
d3 = df.colname.str.extract('([0-9])([0-9])', expand=True)
d3.columns = ['H', 'M']
df = pd.concat([df, d3])
```

However, a good number of the cells in this series just contain

```
'XX45M'
```

or `XX3H`

Is there a way to optionally extract these patterns to insert them into the global df?

For a concrete set of examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['XX1H30M', 'XX45M', 'XX2H'])
```

would end up as

```
Out: 
A  H  M
0  XX1H30M  1  30
1  XX45M  0  45
2  XX2H  2  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some thing like this:

```
df.assign(H=df.A.str.extract('([\d]+)H', expand=False),
          M=df.A.str.extract('([\d]+)M', expand=False)).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
         A  H   M
0  XX1H30M  1  30
1    XX45M  0  45
2     XX2H  2   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option extracting `H` and `M` in one step, here use `(?:(?P<H>\d+)H)?(?:(?P<M>\d+)M)?` to capture `H` and `M` as named groups; To avoid matching empty string due to both groups being optional, add a look ahead assertion `(?=\d+H|\d+M)` at the beginning of the pattern:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['XXX1H30M', 'XXX45M', 'XXX2H', 'XXX']}) 

df.A.str.extract(r'(?=\d+H|\d+M)(?:(?P<H>\d+)H)?(?:(?P<M>\d+)M)?', expand=True).fillna(0)

#   H    M
#0  1   30
#1  0   45
#2  2    0
#3  0    0
```

This is a little bit faster comparing to extract separately:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

%timeit pd.concat([df, df.A.str.extract(r'(?=\d+H|\d+M)(?:(?P<H>\d+)H)?(?:(?P<M>\d+)M)?', expand=False).fillna(0)], axis=1)
#10 loops, best of 3: 83.9 ms per loop    

%timeit df.assign(H=df.A.str.extract('([\d]+)H', expand=False), M=df.A.str.extract('([\d]+)M', expand=False)).fillna(0)
#10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
```